# Post method not allowing data in body request Laravel 9 (postman)

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I've created an api an it works however there is a weird behavior it doesnt allow me to send data in the body of the request.
Here's my code:

api.php

```
Route::controller(AuthController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::post('login', 'login');
    Route::post('register', 'register');
    Route::post('logout', 'logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'refresh');
    Route::get('me', 'me');
});
```

AuthController.php

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login','register']]);
    }

    public function register(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        $token = Auth::login($user);
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'User created successfully',
            'user' => $user,
            'authorisation' => [
                'token' => $token,
                'type' => 'bearer',
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

if i send data like this

```
localhost:8000/api/register?name=odlir4&email=odlirgz4@gmail.com&password=password
```

[image]

it works fine but if i send it like this

[image]

this doesn't work, anyone knows why this is happening? i think it should work or am i wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: ```dd($request()->all());``` at the start of register method and share the output

Comment: select `x-www-form-urlencoded` and try to submit it again

Comment: turned out i didnt realize password has to be 6 characthers min

Answer (score 0):

in the route register you define the **POST** method

api.php

```php
Route::post('register', 'register');
```

in postman you send data using **GET** method because it passes parameter

```
localhost:8000/api/register?name=odlir4&email=odlirgz4@gmail.com&password=password
```

it should be like this in **Tab Body**
https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/published-postman-templates/request/631643-083e46e7-53ea-87b1-8104-f8917ce58a17

Comment: I get what you are saying and that's what I did in the second screens hoot but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to get form-data in your controller using below method

```
public function register(){

  $datarequest = $this->input->post();

// other code

}
```

OR if you want to send request in json

```
public function register(){

  $datarequest = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

// other code

}
```